# Nodejs redis query data

Tags: node.js, redis

I have integrated redis in my node js application. I am using the npm module ["redis"](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis) I am able to set value in the following manner:

```
redisClient.set('users_test', JSON.stringify({name: 'testName', email: 'testEmail', phone: 'testPhone', createdAt: <date>}), redis.print)
redisClient.get('users_test', function(err, users_test) {
            console.log('\n\nREDIS TEST USER: ' + JSON.parse(users_test))
})
```

Consider my application sets 100 such users with different keys in redis. Now I want to retrieve users inserted in a date range. How can I query the redis db like we do in mongodb, mysql, etc. to retrieve data with specific conditions?
I know that I will have to insert the data in some other way instead of string. Please guide me through this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should save each user with uniqe key.

```
redisClient.set('user_' + user_id, ...);
```

Or use different data type, HASH or SORTED SET, in your case, for example. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://redis.io/topics/twitter-clone) , there mentioned all types with usage examples.

Comment: I understand that and I am storing all the users with unique id. But can i query the users with specific conditions.

Comment: Nope, redis actually not for that. The only data type that supports some kind of contitional select is SORTED SET, you can query data by score parameter http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore .

Comment: Ok. So can I do something like -> Get all the objects having key starting with "users_"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming redis is your chosen data backend, the right thing to do is add users to a SORTED SET with `redisClient.zadd(...)` using date as the score. You can later get subsets of the sorted set by score with `redisClient.zrangebyscore(...)`. Read further [here](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#redis-sorted-sets).

Note that if you want to look up users by more than one score (date added), redis becomes less attractive (though still possible).